# From where is it more efficient to call an element from ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm making a deck class, by using a ArrayList to hold multiple Cards (another class I made) However, I can't figure out what my teacher means by this statement when he refers to a `deal` method that returns the top card of the deck:

> Remember that because of the design of an ArrayList, you may deal the top Card, the bottom Card, or any Card from within the Deck. Think about which would be the most efficient implementation.

I always thought that calling an element from the front of any array-type structure is efficient. Is this the case for ArrayList?

What about regular arrays and linkedLists?

---

I meant to put this under the `homework` tag, but it gave me a description stating it was obsolete.

Comment: When you deal a card you'll be removing it from the deck. Which has better performance, removing from front of an arraylist, or the back?

Answer (score 4):

When you deal the card, you are removing a card from the deck, which is different from just accessing the card. Accessing a card would be constant time, but removing is not. When you remove from an `ArrayList`, you need to rearrange all of the elements in the list. Consider this implementation of the `remove` method(from OpenJDK)

```
public E remove(int index) {
   rangeCheck(index);
   modCount++;
   E oldValue = elementData(index);
   int numMoved = size - index - 1;
   if (numMoved > 0)
          System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index, numMoved);
   elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work
   return oldValue;
}
```

So if an element at the front of the list is moved, it has to shift the whole array.

Now in a `LinkedList` implementation, each node just maintains a pointer to the next node, so doing a deletion is simple, it just changes the link of the previous node. Consider this implementation of `remove` in `LinkedList` (again from OpenJDK):

```
private E remove(Entry<E> e) {
       if (e == header)
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
       E result = e.element;
       e.previous.next = e.next;
       e.next.previous = e.previous;
       e.next = e.previous = null;
       e.element = null;
       size--;
       modCount++;
       return result;
}
```

This is not to say that `LinkedList`s are better in every situation. If you need to access a random index of the array, an `ArrayList` is generally much more efficient (a `LinkedList` needs to traverse each node from the beginning of the end until it finds that index).

Comment: So then it would be efficient to remove from the end of the `ArrayList`? So that the subsequent elements don't have to be shifted? After doing so, should I use `.trimToSize()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The Java documentation for classes and methods is what you want to be reading if this is not specifically covered in your class.

In particular, when you "deal" a card from the deck, you're removing it. Reading the [Javadoc for ArrayList.remove(index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) finds:

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. **Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)**.

Think about how that would be applied depending on where in the `ArrayList` you are "dealing" a card from.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList is just an array, inside. So access to any item is O(1). However, removing things is another story. If by 'deal' you mean 'remove it from the list', a bit of thought will reveal to you that it is cheap to remove from one place in an ArrayList, and expensive elsewhere. So, if you must efficiently handle removal from anywhere, you might not want to use an ArrayList.